# Areas of event horizons and singularities from metrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, event-horizon

I am a bit confused about how my lecturer is writing down (seemingly trivially so) areas and lengths associated with event horizons and singularities from the metric.

For example:

> 1. In the Schwarzschild metric in Eddington-Finklestein coordinates, the metric on the event horizon is $$ds^2|_{r= 2m} = 4m^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d\phi^2) $$
>
> **The area of the event horizon is $16\pi m^2$**.

Edit: I think for 1. it may be because the brackets is the metric for a sphere, so we use $4\pi r^2  = 4\pi(4m^2)$?

Another example:

> 2. In the Kerr metric, we find that at the singularity $r=0$ at fixed time and position and on the equatorial plane, the metric is $$ds^2 = a^2 d\phi^2$$ where $a$ is  the angular momentum/spin parameter.  **This implies that the singularity at $r=0$ has** finite length and **circumference $2\pi a$**.

Edit: The second one not sure how we get the length?

I am not understanding how the form of the metrics imply the bold statements.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Schwarzschild radial coordinate, $r$, is *defined* such that, given the 
proper length, $l$ of a small arc on a sphere with centre at the origin 
$$ r = {l\over d\theta}$$
Then it follows immediately that the area of the surface of the sphere at $r=2m$ is $16\pi m^2$.

However, it does *not* follow that this is really a sphere. The event horizon is a boundary on observable spacetime, and there is no empirical definition of anything either on the boundary or inside the event horizon. For example, we can just as easily use a radial coordinate $\rho = r - 2m$, so that the event horizon is actually a point at the origin (much as did Schwarzschild himself). Certainly it is possible to extend the manifold mathematically to the interior solution, but it is not possible to do so within the bounds of empirical science, and we have no valid mathematical argument to say that $r=2m$ is not a singular point with no interior (MTW, for example, extend the manifold by assuming that Einstein's equation should hold on this boundary or singular point, which is not mathematical legitimate and assumes the conclusion). There is nothing in differential geometry to say that a the surface area of a sphere centred at a singular point should not tend to a finite value as the radius tends to zero. Indeed, it is the meaning of a singular point that this can happen.

The same is true whatever coordinates you use (coordinates are arbitrary and do not change geometry). Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates are found by transforming Schwarzschild coordinates. If the event horizon is a boundary, or a singular point, then it remains a boundary or a singular point in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates. Only the description makes it look like it is not a point (just as the North Pole does not look like a point on a typical map of the Earth). In this case, an infalling observer would necessarily be killed at the event horizon rather than almost instantaneously later. In either case, he could offer us no empirical evidence.

Comment: In Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates (as clearly specified in the question) the horizon is not a boundary of the spacetime. It is a plain (and simple) mathematical statement that (at constant time) it has the geometry of a sphere.

Comment: " we have no valid mathematical argument to say that r=2m is not a singular point with no interior" This plain non-sense. You might want read up on the Cauchy evolution of manifolds in general relativity.

Comment: @mmeent, you may want to read up on the meaning of a boundary in topology, and in analysis general, including differential geometry. Physics is not proven by physicists failing to respect elementary mathematical principles.

Comment: Please enlighten us, which definition of boundary does the horizon satisfy in (one of) the Eddington-Finkelstein patch(es)?

Comment: "Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates are found by transforming Schwarzschild coordinates. " No. Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates are a perfectly valid place to start from.

Comment: You can find a definition of a boundary in any suitable mathematical source. It is not helpful to assume the conclusion. If you assume spacetime outside of the boundary, ignoring both mathematics and the empirical basis of science, then of course you can conclude what you assumed in the first place. Ask yourself why you even want to assume something with no empirical basis and no mathematical justification. Just because a mathematical structure is possible, it does not follow that it means anything outside of itself. In the meantime, no discussion of physics is possible here.